Installing bootstrap css file has changed some unicode characters
I just installed bootstrap in my project yesterday and it has changed some of the unicode characters. They aren't jibberish, they just look different to the original ones I used. For example I used a trash can for a delete button and it now looks more like a basketball net.
I have located the problem down to the css file 'bootstrap.min.css'. If I take that out, the problem disappears. I put it back, the problem reappears.
Does anyone know anything about this, or how to fix it etc?

Probably due to the fact, that the elements containing those icon characters, now have a different font-family applied? Go inspect them using your browser dev tools, and compare which font-family is applied in either scenario.
